# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus[version 2](2-variables)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

It is trivial that

By F.T.C , $$\int_a^{b}f'(x)dx (=\int_a^bf_x(t)dt) = F(b)-F(a)$$

when we think about the antiderivative  function, $F$ of the $ f_x$.

So I have a curious that all the possible the 2 variables function cases.

Applying the F.T.C, considering differentiable two variables function whose case is $f(x,y)$

$\int_a^{b}f_x(x,t)dt$

$\int_a^{b}f_x(t,y)dt$

$\int_a^{b}f_y(x,t)dt$

$\int_a^{b}f_y(t,y)dt$

This is my thought that

$f_x(x,b)-f_x(x,a)$ - first example

$f(b,y)-f(a,y)$ - second example

$f(x,b)-f(x,a)$ - third example

$f_y(b,y)-f_x(a,y)$ - 4th example

I'm not sure my answer is correct.

And I'm really confused. What is the difference between those cases?

P.S:  what about the cases 
$\int_b^{t_1}\int_a^{t_2}f_{xy}(x,y)dxdy $?

Also If my answer was correct, I could I prove that? Please give me some hints.

Any answer will be help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think FTC applies to the first and fourth cases, the variable of integration is not the same variable as the variable of differentiation

Comment: Do you meat 1st and 4th cases can't be defined the F.T.C.? plus Are 2nd and 3rd answers correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of multivariable functions, as we are integrating only over 1 variable, the others are effectively constants for the purpose of integration. So, what you have written as the answer is indeed correct.

Similarly, we have $$\int_b^{t_1}\int_a^{t_2}f_{xy}(x,y)dxdy = \int_b^{t_1}(f_{y}(t_2,y)-f_{y}(a,y))dy$$ $$= f(t_2, t_1) - f(t_2, b) - f(a, t_1) + f(a, b)$$

Comment: It think the last term should be $f(a,b)$

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Sorry for bother you, Mr. Ishan Deo. Could you please offer a proof or more explain why My answer was correct? Because MR. WW1 commented the cases 1 and 4th can't apply F.T.C.